# How to restrict a specified file on specified port in Nginx?

Tags: nginx, permissions

The web server is NginX, I need to do these:

1. when accessing xxx.php from port 80, return 404;
2. when accessing xxx.php from 8555(ssl connection), normal way.

I've tried this way:

```
server
{

    listen 80;
    location xxx.php {
        return 404;
    }

    location / {
        .....
    }
}


server
{
    listen 8555 default ssl;
    location / {
        ....
    }
}
```

where `location /{` directive are exactly the same. But it seems does not work.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Use `location /path/to/xxx.php` instead of `location xxx.php`.

Comment: Actually, this configuration is for the proxy server, then how to set the path of xxx.php?

Answer (score 0):

I think I missed an important point, the server is a proxy server, and the upstream server has a lot rewrite rules, so what should be matched here is **not** the file itself, but the url.

so the solution is like this:

find the rewrite rule in the upstream server, locate the key word you want to match, add

```
location ^~ /keyword {
    return 404;
}
```